# How to force Liferay Dev Studio to use the JDK I specified? (JDK8)

Tags: java-8, liferay, ubuntu-18.04, liferay-developer-studio

Liferay Dev Studio is meant to be run with Java 8. I installed it like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/nico/p/jdk8/ LiferayProjectSDKwithDevStudioDXP-2018.11.4-linux-x64-installer.run
```

It asked me what JDK I wanted to use, with the only choice in the list being my JDK8, so I selected that and the installation went on smoothly.

Then I launched it like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/nico/p/jdk8/ ./DeveloperStudio
```

And... it crashes:

[image]

By inspecting `.metadata/.log` I can see that it disregards my choice and uses my system's default JDK instead:

```
!SESSION 2019-01-08 17:29:46.988 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.4.0.201811020125
java.version=10.0.2
```

How to make it use JDK8?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is what DevStudio itself runs under. As it's a version of eclipse, the eclipse configuration works well - just adapt the ini file name to the executable name of DevStudio. Check the [Specifying the VM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) paragraph, and add the following lines to your eclipse.ini, DeveloperStudio.ini (you come up with the proper file name and actual path to your VM)

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe
```

Note: Make it the proper `javaw` executable, not `java`. And yes, I've copied the Windows example even though you tag ubuntu: Your adaptation.